# Angular 5 (RxJS) - call array of subscriptions, then execute code

Tags: angular, rxjs

Response on my main subscription call returns an array of some values. These values are passed as arguments to array of my child subscriptions. In these subscriptions I want to assign values to dataArr - when subscription receives 'Not found' error, then I want to assign custom value. When all of the subscriptions are called then I want to execute final code after last subscription call.

Problem is I can't achieve it with forkJoin, because according to RxJS documentation "If an inner observable does not complete forkJoin will never emit a value!". I've tried merge and concat operators too. Any ideas?

```
this.service.get().subscribe(response => {
  this.observables = [];
  this.dataArr = [];

  response.items.forEach(item => {
    this.observables.push(this.otherService.get(item.data))
    // I want this subscription to make this action
    // this.otherService.get(item.data).subscribe(
    //   response => {
    //     this.dataArr.push({
    //       title: response.title,
    //     });
    //   },
    //   error => {
    //     this.dataArr.push({
    //       title: 'Not found!',
    //     });
    //   }
    // )
  });

  Observable.forkJoin(this.observables).subscribe(
    res => {
      console.log(res)
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
    }, () => {
      console.log('Completed!');
      // execute other code on completion
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: Could you elaborate your question.

Comment: I want to call subscriptions one after another, push data to dataArr array on response or error (commented code) then after last subscription I want to execute some other code. Is this now understandable for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use forkJoin!

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html

*Be aware that if any of the inner observables supplied to forkJoin error you will lose the value of any other observables that would or have already completed **if you do not catch the error correctly on the inner observable**. If you are only concerned with all inner observables completing successfully you can catch the error on the outside.*

So, just make sure that when an observable throws an error, it will still return something:

```
    forkJoin(
        this.service.observableA.pipe(
            map(data => {
                return { result: 'succes', data: data };
            }),
            catchError(err => {
                console.log(err);
                return of({ result: 'failed', data: null });
            })
        ),
        this.service.observableB.pipe(
            map(data => {
                return { result: 'succes', data: data };
            }),
            catchError(err => {
                console.log(err);
                return of({ result: 'failed', data: null });
            })
        )
    ).subscribe(
        // This will be triggered even if one of the observables fail
    );
```

Of course, in the subscribe method, you will need to inspect the list, and check if the 'result' properties is 'succes' or 'failed' for each returned response.

Comment: Changed catchError code to:
`catchError(error => of({ title: 'Not found!' }))`
And it works! Thank you very much :)

Comment: Correct, catchError should indeed return an observable, i'll correct my answer